# Need advice about MVC

Tags: database, hibernate, excel, model-view-controller, struts

I'm still a beginner in MVC, so I have problems in design.

I have many categories C1, C2, C3. Every category has her special structure. So **every category** should be presented in a **Model Class**. I also have for **every category** its own **table in the database**, mapped to eachother by **Hibernate**.

I need in my application, to get the data from an Excel File ( I succeeded the upload and getting data from excel file ). But the excel file should respect the structure of the category chosen in the form. So it means, if I choose in the select of the form C1, then I upload an excel file with a different structure, that file should be rejected...

**So how could I design my application to process Excel files according to the indicated category**??

Comment: You have drowned your question in a lot of information. Is the question about how and where you should process an Excel file to decide if it fits a category ?

Comment: Without further input, I would say that this kind of processing needs to be in either a controller or service.

Comment: @JamesPoulson, well, I made enough information to be clear and to avoid a remark such as "we can't guess much since no enough information".

Comment: @user1459961: you have provided too much information in certain areas (like the packages you have, which shouldn't matter, but make us wonder why you told us about that), and not enough information in other areas (like how the structure of a file is linked to a category. Is it kinked to the class of the category, or to its data, for example). I agree with James, your question could be clearer. And it's your responsibility to make it as clear as possible if you want good answers from people wanting to help, freely, like James.

Comment: @JamesPoulson, I have edited the message and deleted the useless information. Thanks

Comment: @JBNizet, about the structure of Excel : Each Excel file has the same structure of one of the 3 catorgies. Thanks

Comment: @user1459961 Thanks and don't take it badly. I'm not so good with asking questions myself and I know the crowd here on SO is not forgiving. I upvoted your question because it got a -1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an `ExcelStructureValidator` interface, and have all your category classes (C1, C2 and C3) implement an

```
ExcelStructureValidator createExcelStructureValidator()
```

method, which return the appropriate validator for the chosen category.

Other designs could be possible, or even better, but without more information about what a category is and how an excel file structure is linked to a category, it's hard to provide the ideal solution. Some kind of factory for validators based on the category is needed, though. WHether the category should be the factory is debatable.

Comment: Where would you place this validator ? It sounds like our friend here is using layers (domain, dao, service ...) with some MVC mixed in for the front end. Would you have the controller handle this and forward processing to services ?

Comment: Well, in the design I suggested, the validators are direct dependencies of the categories, so they must be part of the domain layer (which, arguably, is not necessarily a good idea. That's why I suggested a more decoupled approach with an external factory). Where the validator is used is another question. I tend to prefer having a very light presentation layer, and to prefer doing this kind of stuff in the service layer. Especially if the validation process needs to access the database.

Comment: Thank you guys, this helped me a lot in conception :) , you all are awsome. +1 to all

Answer (score 0):

If a type of category has been chosen in the form this is a validation task. With a Swing GUI this sort of thing is usually done by an independant class like InputVerifier. This could be integrated in your equivalent of a controller or forwarded to a service.

If you are unsure of the type of category on input you could have a general-purpose method to verify data. If you are expecting a certain category type you could use a factory-style approach to get a specific validator instance that suits the expected category. For these validators you could have a common interface with a `isDataValid` method returning true/false, or using some custom Exceptions for a more fine-grained and OO approach.

Comment: Yes sir. it's what I've decided to have as an approach. Finally, I put it in a service class to avoid making my controller crowded by processing instructions, and in general they are static functions... Thank you again :)